# Cannot recognize class when creating object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create an object of a class in my `mainForm` but it can't recognize the class for some reason:

```
private RecipeManager m_recipeManager = new RecipeManager();
```

> The type or namespace name 'RecipeManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my `RecipeManager` class:

```
public class RecipeManager : ListManager<Recipe>
{
    public RecipeManager()
    {

    }
}
```

I am able to create object out of my other manager classes such as:

```
private AnimalManager animalmgr = new AnimalManager(); //This works
```

The `AnimalManager` class:

```
public class AnimalManager : ListManager<Animal>
{
    private int startID = 100;

    public AnimalManager()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the RecipeManager class definition is in the same assembly as where you have private RecipeManager m_recipeManager = new RecipeManager(); ?

Comment: In what namespace is `RecipeManager` defined?  In what namespace is the class where you're trying to create an instance of it?

Comment: Thank you. I realized now that they weren't defined in the same namespace. Beginner mistake I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
private AnimalManager animalmgr = new AnimalManager();
```

When you create an object, no need to define it private , public,...

```
AnimalManager animalmgr = new AnimalManager();
```

And define them in same namespace or you can delete the namespace{}, it still works.

Comment: But thank you. Can you help me display the `ingredient` to the listbox on the previous question please. The `name` was was working.